# SQL Delete from and get field back

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

I want to run a SQL query which deletes from a table under conditions but also returns a column of the data being deleted so that the I can do some work with it on the server.

Obviously I could split them into two queries such as:

```sql
SELECT name 
FROM users
WHERE username = '...';
```

```sql
DELETE FROM users
WHERE username = '...';
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to use parameters or possibly `PRINT` to only send one query that would delete and return the `name` field of the item being deleted. Is this possible or should I stick to two queries?

Comment: [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). [Capturing the results of the DELETE statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#CaptureResults)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `OUTPUT` keyword on a `DELETE` (and `UPDATE` / `INSERT`) to caputure the deleted rows. You will need to capture into a temp table (or table variable) to do something with it:

```
CREATE TABLE #Del
(
    [name] VARCHAR (25)
)

DELETE FROM Users
OUTPUT DELETED.name
INTO #Del
WHERE UserName = 'John.Doe';  

SELECT * FROM #Del -- do what you need to do here

DROP TABLE #Del
```

Comment: Interesting, so is `#Del` temporary. I am just thinking if a second user were to delete their account then wouldn't the `SELECT * FROM #Del` return two users when I want the immediate current deletion?

Comment: #Del is a temporary table. A temp table only lives for the session and is not accessible from another users session (However a global temp table such as ##Del is accessible across sessions) I have amended the code as I did not tidy up the temp table which is good practice

Comment: It works but I am now wondering why this is a better approach to just running a select before the delete? Surely it has additional overhead creating and remove the table each time?